# How to connect dishwasher air gap to sink tailpiece?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

So I bought this air gap: https://www.homedepot.com/p/PartsmasterPro-Dishwasher-Air-Gap-with-Cover-in-Chrome-58454/300733089

And this tailpiece: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-x-8-in-Plastic-Dishwasher-Branch-Tailpiece-C9816/205153966

The output of the air gap is 7/8" barb and the input of the tailpiece is 1/2" barb, what's the correct way to connect these? The only thing I've really seen/figured is a universal dishwasher drain pipe but that's 6ft long to cover a ~1ft distance which seems crazy since I'm already going 6ft from the dishwasher to the air gap. Should I be using vinyl tubing and maybe something like 3/4" ID and clamp super hard on the 1/2" and press really hard to get it onto the 7/8" or something else?

Underside of sink for reference:
[image: underside of sink]

Comment: Are you sure you need to use an air gap? If you are permitted by code in your area to use a high hose loop instead then you can just run the dishwasher hose up in a loop and right down to the tailpiece. The 1/2" on the tailpiece should be the same as the 1/2" input on the air gap, so if it fits one it will fit the other - and in fact that may be why the tailpiece has 1/2" instead of 7/8".

Answer (score 1):

My dishwasher is installed using only the "everbuilt" part with the "Y" and not an air gap. My son has his installed as Manassehkatz stated. They both work great.